# Spring-Data-Jpa bidirectional association with EmbeddedId. Foreign key is null when merging

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am running the latest version of Hibernate with 2 entities: `Project` and `ProjectShare`, which have a one-to-many relation set up bidirectional.

A `ProjectShare` is uniquely identified by a composite ID containing `project_id` and `user_id`. Besides the key, a `ProjectShare` contains a boolean flag whether the user gets read or write access on the project.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue // UUID generator
    @Column(name = "project_id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<ProjectShare> shares = new ArrayList<>();

    public Project(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addShare(ProjectShare share) {
        shares.add(share);
        share.setProject(this);
    }

    public void removeShare(ProjectShare share) {
        shares.remove(share);
        share.setProject(null);
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "project_shares")
public class ProjectShare {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ProjectShareId id;

    @Column(name = "has_write_access")
    private boolean hasWriteAccess;

    @MapsId("projectId")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Project project;

    public ProjectShare(ProjectShareId id, boolean hasWriteAccess) {
        this.id = id;
        this.hasWriteAccess = hasWriteAccess;
    }

    public void setProject(Project project) {
        this.project = project;
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class ProjectShareId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "project_id")
    private String projectId;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;

    public ProjectShareId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    // equals and hashCode go here...
}
```

If I create a new `Project` and assign new `ProjectShare` associations to it, everything works fine:

```
Project project = new Project("my_project");
project.addShare(new ProjectShare(new ProjectShareId("user1"), false));
project.addShare(new ProjectShare(new ProjectShareId("user2"), false));
projectRepository.save(project); // assume project id is '123'
```

Since all objects are new and not yet persisted, it executes 1 insert for the Project itself and 1 insert for each ProjectShare. Lets assume the project is inserted with id '123'.

Now, if I load this existing project, and add new ProjectShares to it, things go wrong:

```
Project project = projectRepository.findById("123");
project.addShare(new ProjectShare(new ProjectShareId("user2"), true));
project.addShare(new ProjectShare(new ProjectShareId("user3"), true));
projectRepository.save(project);
```

For every ProjectShare, this executes a SELECT on the values in `ProjectShareId` (project_id and user_id), followed by either an INSERT of UPDATE, depending on whether the record was found. This is the basic *merge* strategy of Hibernate and this is what we want.

The desired outcome of this should be:

- Leave ProjectShare for `user1` untouched
- Update the ProjectShare for `user2` (from `false` to `true`)
- Create a new ProjectShare for `user3`

However, when the SELECT is executed for the `ProjectShare`, **the foreign key project_id is always null**. This means that existing records are never found, an INSERT is attempted instead of and UPDATE, and a DB-level Constraint violation is triggered.

How should I solve this issue? Should I manually go through the `project.getShares()` collection, find existing records and update them instead? I was hoping Hibernate would do this through its merge strategy.

Or could this be a bug in Hibernate related to associations with foreign keys in Embbedded IDs?

Comment: I presume it is because you have defined lazy fetching for the project_id with the annotation `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`, so the project_id is not fetched.

Comment: This is not about fetching from database, but about the order of assignment. If I call `setProject()` on a `ProjectShare` with an existing entity, its corresponding foreign key `projectId` is not set. This causes a mismatch when merging.

Comment: *Update the ProjectShare for user2 (from false to true)*. If you want to modify an existing instance you load that existing instance and change it. You **don't** create a new instance with the same ID and modify that.

Comment: Sure, I could do that explicitly, iterating over the 'shares' collection in Project, update those affected and insert new ones, but that defeats the purpose of Hibernate's merge operation. If what you're saying is true, then why does Hibernate do a select before insert?